# How to combine two git hosted projects into one fork in a way, that both can be updated easily?

Tags: git

There are two projects: `micropython` and `lvgl` (a gui), both maintained by different persons, both are git repos.
Both can be combined technically into one to build a "python programmable gui for microcontrollers". Most of the code don't overlap, only a few changes need to be mad`enter code here`e to make `micropython` "`lvgl`-aware".
There is a repo of a combination of both already, but that one is outdated slightly and something is wrong with the git-related metadata. So I want to try my own attempt to combine both.

Is it possible to combine both into one repo in a way, that is easy to update `lvgl` as it is easy to update `micropython` ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a better structure would be to write something that sits on top of both of these projects (uses `micropython` and `lvgl` as dependencies), rather than modifying the base projects for your specific application. If you then need to make changes to either one of the projects to make them more generic/extensible, those changes should be merged into the base projects. This approach has other benefits. It allows you to abstract away any implementation details in the dependency, and provide the interface you want.

Comment: Unfortunately I am bound to the method of combining both due to technical reasons. Therefore I want to repeat my inital question here about how to setup what I have described above.

Comment: Please expand on your reason for the limitation?

Comment: lvgl works as a module for µpython - it becomes in integral part and as such needs to be refered by µpython as a part of its set of commands. Therefore this implies a hierarchical structure, which needs to be drastically changed when trying to put both side by side glued together by a third layer. The latter would imply much more changes than merge both together manually for each newupdate. Additionally I have not the time to dive that deep into the internal structure - a heavily optimized language interpreter and compiler and the implementation of a gui framework to make the latter possible.